# What does 帰れん mean?

Tags: meaning, auxiliary-ず

from the youtube channel 釣れるまで帰れん is it won't go back or can't go back if translated or neither?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12225/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16226/9831

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「帰{かえ}**ら**ん」＝「帰**ら**ない」 = "not / will not return (home)"

「帰**れ**ん」＝「帰**れ**ない」 = "cannot / will not be able to return (home)"

The latter is in the **negative potential** form.

This 「ん」 has been discussed many times before; hence, just a short answer.